# how to customize width as per label on @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I had bottom bar I need it to be like that

[image]

but I can't update width for each item
[image]

Comment: did you figure out the problem?

Comment: no I can't solve this issue @Nivethan

Comment: looks like we can control the container using tabBarItemStyle inside screenOptions and by default it uses flex so all children takes same width and space, to me it feels intuitive for a navigation.  but you can set padding to the tabBarItemStyle which adds space around your icons and label